# Convert numbers to strings

Tags: dafny

I am trying to write a function which takes in `val:nat, votes: set<nat>, N: nat` where `N` is the maximum size of the set, `votes`, and returns a string which concatenates the `val` and `votes`.

Example: H(val: 23, votes:{1,3}, N: 3) will return "23-1-0-3"

Any leads is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

There's no built-in conversion of numbers to strings. You can write a function to do it. (If you do, you're welcome to file a Pull Request on the under-utilized https://github.com/dafny-lang/libraries .)

Note, if you only need to print the number, you can do that with the `print` statement.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following conversion from nat to string, which has the feature that it's proven in both sides.
You can safely use `Printer.natToString` in contexts where you only expects a `string`, as it provides more guarantee about this string than you would need though.
I used `{:options "/functionSyntax:4"}` so that the functions below are compilable without using the "method" keyword.

```
module {:options "/functionSyntax:4"} Printer {

  type stringNat = s: string |
    |s| > 0 && (|s| > 1 ==> s[0] != '0') &&
    forall i | 0 <= i < |s| :: s[i] in "0123456789"
    witness "1"

  function natToString(n: nat): stringNat {
    match n
    case 0 => "0" case 1 => "1" case 2 => "2" case 3 => "3" case 4 => "4"
    case 5 => "5" case 6 => "6" case 7 => "7" case 8 => "8" case 9 => "9"
    case _ => natToString(n / 10) + natToString(n % 10)
  }

  function stringToNat(s: stringNat): nat
    decreases |s|
  {
    if |s| == 1 then
      match s[0]
      case '0' => 0 case '1' => 1 case '2' => 2 case '3' => 3 case '4' => 4
      case '5' => 5 case '6' => 6 case '7' => 7 case '8' => 8 case '9' => 9
    else
      stringToNat(s[..|s|-1])*10 + stringToNat(s[|s|-1..|s|])
  }

  lemma natToStringThenStringToNatIdem(n: nat)
    ensures stringToNat(natToString(n)) == n
  { // Proof is automatic
  }
  lemma stringToNatThenNatToStringIdem(n: stringNat)
    ensures natToString(stringToNat(n)) == n
  { // Proof is automatic
  }
}
```